# How to decode encoded special XML characters in a string?

Tags: java

I was given a string like

```
example.com/test?region=us&amp;lang=en&amp;jurisdiction=us
```

How can I write the java code to decode the encoded characters like

```
&amp;
```

in the string. Is there any existing class/method to decode them?

Thanks.

Comment: They don't look encoded to me.

Comment: Indeed, those are escaped HTML/XML entities. They needs to be unescaped.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To unescape HTML/XML entities, use [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) [`StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) or [homegrow one](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/UnescapeHTML.htm).

Comment: Homegrowing your own is probably a bad idea; use the Apache library.

Comment: @sean: even more, homegrowing is always a bad idea. The link is just there to show how it could be done, for the interested or for ones who have a stupid manager who decided a "no 3rd party libraries" restriction.

Comment: I really disagree on the "always a bad idea" part. I have really a problem if someone uses external libraries only to use a few functions. Let alone the version management if (always apache) libraries clashes.

Comment: @Waverick: I agree your disagreement.

Answer (score 2):

[StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) seems to escape everything

Answer (score 0):

You can also include special characters in XPL. XPL has exactly the same structure as XML, but allows special characters. There is an XML parser with source code available for transformations at http://hll.nu