# change all xml entities to html

Tags: java, xml

I am reading a document which may contain XML entities like `&#160`.

Since I need to export txt file, I manually have to convert the entities from XML to text.

As you can see below.

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"));
while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
 if (s.equals("&#160"))
   s= " ";
}
```

Since there are many xml entities, and I want to convert them all to text like `&#160`->space, and prefer to avoid if then, is there a generic way to do it?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please show some sample input and output.

Comment: I added some more info. thanks!

Comment: You're talking about entities, not tags. Edited question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you extract the number from `&#160;`, you can do this:

```
(new String(new byte[]{(byte)160}, "ISO-8859-1")).
```

Here are the entity mappings: [HTML ISO-8859-1 Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're talking about is called HTML (not XML) **decoding**.  There is a [URLDecoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) class which does this for URLs (which may be what you're decoding).  There is also a more general class in Apache commons for HTML decoding (specified in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994331/java-how-to-decode-html-character-entities-in-java-like-httputility-htmldecode)).

Edit: I was unaware of the difference between HTML and XML escapes/entities, thanks for the clarification.  It appears from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241787/how-to-decode-encoded-special-xml-characters-in-a-string) that Apache commons has a library for decoding XML entities but the standard Java library does not.

Comment: I am actually looking for XML decoding. &#160 is XML entity and not HTML which will be &nbps;.

Comment: URL decoding changes `%20` to a space; entity decoding changes `&#x20;` or `&#32;` to a space, or `&#160;` to a non-breaking space - "Numeric character entity references" are valid in both XML and HTML, not XML only.