# Decoding the Special characters retrieved from the XML file

Tags: java

This is regarding decoding the special characters from the XML file which is internally retrieved from the data base through parser. The partial data that we got is

```
&quot;qutes&quot;, sigle quotes&#39;, namne?
```

Here, the XML character ' `&quot;` should be converted to plain quotes like ". In the similar way `'&#39;'` which is a single quote(apostrophes).
    Is there any way to do this in JAVA. Kindly, let me know if you need any information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode encoded special XML characters in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241787/how-to-decode-encoded-special-xml-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

If you parse your XML with Stax or DOM this would be handled automatically. If not there is a duplicate thread here: [How to decode encoded special XML characters in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241787/how-to-decode-encoded-special-xml-characters-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHTML()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

> Unescapes a string containing entity escapes to a string containing the actual Unicode characters corresponding to the escapes. Supports HTML 4.0 entities.
>   For example, the string "`&lt;Fran&ccedil;ais&gt;`" will become "`<Français>`"
>   If an entity is unrecognized, it is left alone, and inserted verbatim into the result string. e.g. "`&gt;&zzzz;x`" will become "`>&zzzz;x`".

Answer (score 0):

Use:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseString%28java.lang.String%29

Also consider to use JAXB, which will do all the conversions for you.

Comment: there was no error - it simply didn't decode the standard set of entities for XML, I tried something like: "one&amp;two" and the underlying method returned the same string?

Answer (score 0):

You can used PrintWriter . println. You can also now use XPL to store data rather than XML. [XPL is just like XML, but allows special characters in text elements](http://hll.nu/xpl/xpl1.htm).