# Ajax Response for a JSON Data

Tags: java, ajax, json, response

I am using AJAX to cal my struts action class and it's storing some data in session.

```
public String myMethod(){
     session.put("DATA", JSON_STRING); //JSON formatted string
     return "forward";
}
```

I am forwarding to a jsp page in which I am printing this data

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<s:property value="#session['DATA']" />
```

So in the end I am receiving the AJAX Call Response

```
[{&quot;title&quot;: &quot;OFP LALOUV0042/ODF96-02 PD/FP16 (L)&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;551&quot;}]
```

What I am expecting is

```
[{"title": "OFP LALOUV0042/ODF96-02 PD/FP16 (L)", "key": "551"}]
```

Comment: I don't agree on your approach, but in your case, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241787/how-to-decode-encoded-special-xml-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<s:property value="#session['DATA']" escapeHtml="false" />
```

Comment: Indeed this works  <s:property value="#session['DATA'] escape="false" />